# Give access to proper user agent

Tags: php, user-agent

I want to give access to noted user agent, and to deny for rest user agents.

I have following script , but something is wrong here :

```
<?php

if( ($_GET['user_agent'],"DuneHD/1.0 (product_id: hdtv_101; firmware_version: 150721_0135_b9)")) {
 header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');

}

else {

    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');

}

?>
```

Comment: what level of security are you hoping to gain out of denying users based on their user agent?

Comment: This is just one part of security . And in this part I want to just deny access for some services for rest of user agent s.

Comment: What is the problem...specify?

Comment: Script is not working. Its like something is missing in if()

Comment: Don't you need to compare like this `if( $_GET['user_agent']==="DuneHD/1.0 (product_id: hdtv_101; firmware_version: 150721_0135_b9)")`?

Comment: Tried. Give access from different user agents.

Comment: Sanity check: Should you not use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` rather than `$_GET['user_agent']`?

Comment: My service that i am using can get only like i wrote. It is tested and $_GET['user_agent'], give what i need.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you are looking for is just:

```
if( $_GET['user_agent'] == "DuneHD/1.0 (product_id: hdtv_101; firmware_version: 150721_0135_b9)" ) {
  ...
}
```

There was en error in your if statement.

Comment: I tried that also, its give me access from other user agent